# Programmatically set margins in report viewer control

Tags: vb.net, .net-2.0, reportviewer, margins

In onw of our application, we have some reports that need very specific margins that are dependant of the printer the user have. It is used to print into preformatted paper with blanks to fill and depending of the printer, the printing is off by some margins. To make things worse, we don't actually control what printer is used because it is not an internal application.

The only solution I could think of is to let the user configure the margins somehow. I thought I could just dynamically change the report margins like I did with datasources and actual report (I have one control that is used to display every reports from my application and it works alright), but I can't seem to find that damn property to do so. There is a margin property on the report viewer but it's for the form display so it doesn't cut it.

Does anyone knows how to. What I was thinking to do is to define the margins before the user loads the report, i.e. when he clicks on the report button, I load the report, set the margins (or vice-versa is necessary) and then display it.

Before someone mention it, I know the user can, once the report is loaded, change the page setup to fit his needs, but this has two drawbacks. First one is that it is not saved each time and I need it to be 'saveable' and by users. The second one is that Report viewer seems to have some bugs when the regional setting aren't set to what it's expecting and we can't force the users to changes their setting to accommodate one application.

Edit: Forgot to mention, it this is of any uses. My reports are all local reports.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I don't care how it is done, as long as it is done... I don't care if I have to create a copy of the report file and edit the file 'manually' if that's the only way to do it... Actually this would work, but I'de rather find a more elegant way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this directly. Try controlling your margins in the report with report parameters.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean? If you mean in the design mode, then I can't really do that. Like mentionned, I need to be able to let any user change it according to his printer. I know it's quite a hassle, but I can't negotiate that. Trust me, I tried to... :o

Comment: In design mode, instead of entering a numeric value, use an expression that references a report parameter. You can let the user type in the parameter, or provide it in some other fashion, when the report is rendered.

Comment: This would have been really nice but it doesn't work. 
I tired it already, when I input something else than absolute value (meaning I try to do Parameters!MarginLeft.Value), it gives me an error. I tried with CDbl(Parameters!MarginLeft.Value) and I got the same result

Comment: You are right - margins can't be expressions. I guess that leaves you only with one option - manipulating the RDLC before it is loaded, like you already suggested. Btw, there is an example for this technique on gotreportviewer.com.

Answer (score 3):

```
    'creates a new page setting
    Dim instance As New PageSettings()
    'create the new margin values (left,right,top,bottom)
    Dim value As New Margins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    'gives your new pagesetting a value
    instance.Margins = value

    'report viewer now sets your margins
    ReportViewer1.SetPageSettings(instance)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I just had this similar problem; needed a report to have 0" margins, otherwise the blasted thing went from 2 pages to 6, and it split the data vertically, so the pages made no sense.  I was having to set it manually in the Print Setup to print, but the end goal of this report is to be emailed to customers as a PDF, and guess what, when I set the margins manually and exported, it still split into 6 pages and bombed out.  So risking everything, I tried one last supreme effort to fix this blasted thing - I opened up the .rdlc with word pad, and miracle of miracles, found 1in, etc.  I set all those buggers to 0in, saved, ran my .net code (2008), opened up Print Setup, and hallelujah, there was my 0in settings.  Now for the supreme test - I exported it as a PDF, went to the file, and son of a gun!  Sweet.  There were two crisp clean perfectly laid out pages.  All was beneficent in the universe, I calmed down and let the midiclorians flow through me, and just basked in a moment so rare that it is rarely realized by some - a simple fix.

Comment: I realize this solution doesn't cover changing the report margins dynamically for different users.  However, it solved my problem of needing to set custom margins for a given report.  As described above I opened the .rdlc file for edit and found these lines:

    <LeftMargin>1in</LeftMargin>
    <RightMargin>1in</RightMargin>
    <TopMargin>1in</TopMargin>
    <BottomMargin>1in</BottomMargin>

I edited those and ran the report which had the custom margin settings in place.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [ReportPageSettings class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportpagesettings_members(VS.80).aspx), part of the report viewer control. Setting those values looks like it should get you what you need.

Comment: Sounds nice but I can't seem to find how to set the values (is it on the local report property, report viewer, or other?)

Answer (score 0):

More settings;

```
        Dim myPageSettings As New PageSettings()
        myPageSettings.Margins = New Margins(0, 0, 0 , 0)
        Dim paperSize As PaperSize = New PaperSize()
        'ToDo: update with the PaperKind 
        'that your printer uses
        paperSize.RawKind = PaperKind.A4
        ' paperSize.RawKind = System.Drawing.Printing.PaperKind.A4
        myPageSettings.PaperSize = paperSize
        'False for "Portrait"
        'True for "Landscape"
        myPageSettings.Landscape = False

        'report viewer now sets your margins
        ReportViewer1.SetPageSettings(myPageSettings)
```

Comment: Where can I find the PageSetting() class?
Thank you

Comment: Where can I find the PageSetting class?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

this code work with me, the numbers in mm

```
Dim newPageSettings As New System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings
newPageSettings.Margins = New System.Drawing.Printing.Margins(50, 100, 45, 45)
ReportViewer1.SetPageSettings(newPageSettings)
```

im using vb.net 2013